# unicode zero width joiner to normal space

Tags: ruby, unicode, gsub

I have this text

```
  file1 = "</span>‍foo"
```

hidden between the ">" and the "f" is a zero width joiner (\u200D) 
I want to change this to a normal space (\u0020) 
This is what I've tried

```
   file1 = file1.gsub(/\u200D/, ' ')
```

And this is the result

```
   file2.puts file1 #=> </span>?foo
```

For some reason it's inserted a question mark there. even if i don't replace it with anything and just do

```
file1.puts file2
```

It still comes out with a question mark  (it only seems to come up with the question mark if you're taking the text from one file and outputting to another file)
I want the end result to be

```
file1.puts file2 #=> </span>‍ foo
```

**I am not trying to parse html using ruby**

Comment: Is there something else in that string perhaps? What does `file1.bytes` show?

Comment: @matt this comes up with a list of numbers: 
`60
 47
115
112
97
110
62
226
128
141
102
111
111`
no idea what that means

Comment: It’s the values of the bytes that make up that string (in UTF-8 encoding – the bytes `226 128 141` are the zero width joiner). It looks correct, so there doesn’t seem to be anything else there. What does `file2.bytes` show?

Answer (score 4):

200d is not thin space, but "zero width joiner", it has non-space-like properties. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm

First off, the basic regexp works for me:

```
irb(main):042:0> "\u200d".gsub(/\u200d/,"xxx")
=> "xxx"
```

[[:space:]] does not (would not have expected either, since it's stone age POSIX stuff... and 200d is not space anyways):

```
irb(main):003:0> "\u200d".gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"xxx")
=> "‍"
```

\u200d does not count as Separator:Space:

```
irb(main):005:0> "\u200d".gsub(/\p{Cf}/,"xxx")
=> "‍"
```

But it matches Other:Format

```
irb(main):006:0> "\u200d".gsub(/\p{Cf}/,"xxx")
=> "xxx"
```

Source: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html

Comment: it only seems to come up with the question mark if you're outputting it into another file

Comment: ok well im an idiot and it's just occured to me that the files im going from and to need to convert to UTF-8 thanks for the help